# Cannot resole token 'AbstractCalendarViewDelegate' from CalendarView

Tags: android, calendar, widget, importerror, calendarview

I am new to developing in Android, and I'm trying to create a CalendarView with a different number of days per month than the regular calendar (think Lunar month instead of Gregorian)

After poking around I saw on https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/CalendarView.java that the class has an abstract method named AbstractCalendarViewDelegate that seems to be overridable for developers that wish to do just that, starting at line 650

```
/**
 * An abstract class which can be used as a start for CalendarView implementations
 */
abstract static class AbstractCalendarViewDelegate implements CalendarViewDelegate {...}
```

However, trying to create a class extending this one gives a 'Cannot resole token 'AbstractCalendarViewDelegate' error, as seen here: [Error shown in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAIB1.png)

How do I configure my IDE to import the right package to enable me to use the abstract method in my code?